# Как сделать запрос, что бы вывелись за один раз все нужные данные?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно получить данные о количестве клиентов, проживавших в отеле от 1 до 3, от 3 до 10 и свыше 10 суток, в процентном выражении от общего количества клиентов.

```
SELECT  (COUNT("name")::real  / COUNT("name")::real *100) AS "ratio"
FROM "Client"
WHERE "num_room" IN
(SELECT "num_room"
FROM "Room"
WHERE ("dateOfLeaving" - "dateOfSettle" >=1 AND "dateOfLeaving" - 
"dateOfSettle" <= 3) OR
("dateOfLeaving" - "dateOfSettle" >=3 AND "dateOfLeaving" - "dateOfSettle" 
<= 10) OR 
"dateOfLeaving" - "dateOfSettle" >=10)
```

Заполненные таблицы:
[image: Заполненная таблица: клиент]
[image: Заполненная таблица: комната]
Вот то, что у меня получилось. Проблема в том, что считается к-ство уже с учетом условия и выводится только одна колонка со значениями.

[image: Вывод]

Мне нужно, что бы для каждого условия выводился свой столбец отношения и при этом это отношение считалось правильно( в моем случае считаются клиенты, которые проживали соответственное к-ство дней и делятся на то же число, а нужно, что бы делились на общее к-ство клиентов).

Comment: Где исходные данные - DDL таблицы, пример наполнения, результат при таком наполнении? В общем случае - отдельные поля формируем соответствующими CASE или, если поддержано, оконными функциями.

Comment: в общем виде количество по условию получается с помощью `sum(case when условие then 1 else 0 end)` в условие подставляете как в where что то, что определит количество дней

Comment: @Akina добавил примеры

Comment: для начала выбрасываете вообще все условия из where. если присмотреться к ним, то видно, что они фактически выбирают все данные из БД, потому что дополняют друг друга для выбора всех возможных вариантов. А потом вот те условия что выбросили пишите каждое в отдельный sum(case), что я привел выше

Comment: @Mike спасибо! все получилось.